# Split String inside Comma Except Specific Word that Containing Hash

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find what regular expression that match for my needs.

Lets say I have string :

```
one, two, three, #four, five
```

I want to split text above and ignore **#four**, so I would like the string to be spit like :

```
one, two, three, five
```

I really appreciated for any help from you :)

Comment: Split with ", " and filter out entries starting with a hash.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/pn9sywee/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need regex just split and filter and finaly join :

```
var str = "one, two, three, #four, five";
var result = str.split(",").filter(elem => !elem.includes("#")).join(",");
console.log(result);  // one, two, three, five
```